# Map table without bean

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm not sure if the title is right... But here is my problem

This is my bean class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Exercise")
public class Exercise {
    private IntegerProperty exerciseID;
    private ObjectProperty<String> name;
    private ObjectProperty<ExerciseCategory> category;
    private ObservableList<Parameter> parameters;

    public Exercise(int exerciseID, String name, ExerciseCategory category){
        this.exerciseID = new SimpleIntegerProperty(exerciseID);
        this.name = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(name);
        this.category = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(category);
        parameters = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    }

    public Exercise(){
        this(0,null, null);
    }

    public Exercise(String name, ExerciseCategory category){
        this(0, name, category);
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public int getExerciseID() {
        return exerciseID.get();
    }

    public IntegerProperty exerciseIDProperty() {
        return exerciseID;
    }

    public void setExerciseID(int exerciseID) {
        this.exerciseID.set(exerciseID);
    }

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    public String getName() {
        return name.get();
    }

    public ObjectProperty<String> nameProperty() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name.set(name);
    }

    @OneToOne
    public ExerciseCategory getCategory() {
        return category.get();
    }

    public ObjectProperty<ExerciseCategory> categoryProperty() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(ExerciseCategory category) {
        this.category.set(category);
    }

    public ObservableList<Parameter> getParameters() {
        return parameters;
    }

    public void setParameters(ObservableList<Parameter> parameters) {
        this.parameters = parameters;
    }
}
```

One exercise can have one more parameters. This mapping is saved in the ExerciseParameter table, which looks like this:

```
ExerciseParameter
ExerciseID int(11) PK
ParameterID int(11) PK
```

My question is, how do I map this in the Exercise class? Because I don't want to make a ExerciseParamter class...

Thank you!

Comment: can you Parameter Entity also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a `many-to-many` relationship. You can use `@ManyToMany` annotion to do that.

Add following Annotation into `getParameters` method of `Employee` Entity

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinTable(name="ExerciseParameter", 
            joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="ExerciseID ")}, 
            inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="ParameterID")})
```

And also add following Annotation into `getEmployees` method of `Parameter` entity. *(You have not presented the `Parameter` Entity. I assume that `Parameter` class contains the `getEmployees` method.)*

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="parameters")
```